# Long table command does not execute in IEEE template

Tags: tables, longtable

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{longtable}{rr}[H]
\centering \small
\caption{Description of acronyms} \label{tab1}
\label{ACR}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
ICT & Information and communication technology\\



\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by providing two `\label` instructions?

Comment: `longtable` environments cannot be used in two-column documents. The `IEEEtran` document class sets up two-column mode, though.

Comment: Sorry, it does not help that you ask one question after the other but never react on comments asking for important informations. You **never upvoted or accepted** one of the given answers what is the way here to say "Thank You" for the help. Please check your old questions, consider upvoting and accepting and learn from the given answers before asking new questions ... Help us to help you with reacting to the comments!